# Cannot create mySQL database

Tags: mysql, c

I'm a newbie in mySQL programming, and seems to have encountered a very basic problem.

I have the following code, but got segmentation fault at the "create database" part.

```
MYSQL *s1;
MYSQL mysql_sense;
char strBuf[8192] = {0};
char DB_NAME[300] = "0_4_3";

mysql_init(&mysql_sense);

sprintf(strBuf, "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s;", DB_NAME);
mysql_real_query(&mysql_sense, strBuf, strlen(strBuf));  // seg fault here
```

I tried

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS 0_4_3
```

in the actual mySQL, and there wasn't any errors. Why do I get seg fault in my code?

Comment: It would help if you tagged this with the appropriate language. That way more people can help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't do a `mysql_connect()` or a `mysql_real_connect()`.
2. You don't check the return value of `mysql_init()`.

Comment: I connected to a NULL database first, then created the database I wanted. It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be unrelated to your problem, but the documentation says that:

> **By default**, mysql_query() and mysql_real_query() interpret their
>   statement string argument as a **single statement** to be executed, and
>   you process the result according to whether the statement produces a
>   result set (a set of rows, as for SELECT) or an affected-rows count
>   (as for INSERT, UPDATE, and so forth).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//c-api-multiple-queries.html

Since you only have one statement the simplest fix it to drop the trailing semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the semi-colon didn't cause the error.